# Understanding of a sentence

Tags: meaning

> The latest UPS “Pain in the (Supply) Chain” survey shows that an
>   environment of increasing risks, complex regulations and continuing
>   cost pressures are the three key issues faced by the healthcare
>   industry around the world and in Asia, where regulatory compliance or
>   changing/increasing regulations are the factors that are most driving
>   changes in the supply chain.

How to divide the sentence according to meaning? I think it is "The latest UPS 'Pain in the (Supply) Chain' survey //shows //that an environment of increasing risks, complex regulations and continuing cost pressures are the three key issues faced by the healthcare industry around the world /and in Asia, where regulatory compliance or changing/increasing regulations are the factors that are most driving changes in the supply chain." Am I right? I am confused with "in Asia, where regulatory compliance or changing/increasing regulations are the factors that are most driving changes in the supply chain". Is it a phrase? Or I understand the sentence wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

> The latest UPS “Pain in the (Supply) Chain” survey shows that an environment of increasing risks, complex regulations and continuing cost pressures are the three key issues faced by the healthcare industry around the world and in Asia, where regulatory compliance or changing/increasing regulations are the factors that are most driving changes in the supply chain.

Let's disassemble:

> A survey was conducted. Its results show that three key issues exist for the healthcare industry. These issues are: an environment of increasing risks; complex regulations; continuing cost pressures. Where do they affect the healthcare? Oh, around the world! And specifically in Asia: in this part of the world, regulatory compliance or changing/increasing regulations are the factors that are most driving changes in the supply chain

Answer (score 0):

The passage is verbose and has some grammatical errors.

error of agreement:  *Environment....are.*  One could simply eliminate "an environment of".

the factors that are *most driving* changes...  I would say instead: ...driving most...

And we also have  a singular noun connected to a plural noun by "or" as subject of a plural verb, which is at the very least an infelicity:

*regulatory compliance or changing/increasing regulations  are the factors that are...*